# Book Cover with pstricks - turns colored image to Black and White image

Tags: pstricks, book-design, books

I'm trying to make Book back cover with `pstricks`. I have one issue with it, it turns my colored image to Black and White image. Any help to overcome this problem is highly appreciated. Thanks

**Output**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
% load the necessary packages 
\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,prologue,table]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[ISBN=978-80-85955-35-4]{ean13isbn}

%\EANisbn[SC4]
% begin the document and suppress page numbers
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{Maroon}
\pagestyle{empty}

% set up the picture environment
\psset{unit=1in}
\begin{pspicture}(13.24in,9in)
% set up the fonts we use
\DeclareFixedFont{\PT}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.65in}
\DeclareFixedFont{\PTsmall}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.5in}
\DeclareFixedFont{\PTsmallest}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.4in}
\DeclareFixedFont{\PTtext}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{12pt}
\DeclareFixedFont{\Logo}{T1}{pbk}{m}{n}{0.2in}



% put the publisherӳ logo on the spine
\rput[b](6.65,-1.00){\color{white}{\fbox{\Logo ASD}}}
% Create a Box containing the text for the back cover
\newsavebox\Blurbbox
\sbox\Blurbbox{\begin{minipage}{4.5in}
\textcolor{white}{%
  \large{%
  This booklet contains
  }
}

\end{minipage}}
% And position the box
\rput[tl](1,8){\usebox\Blurbbox}
% Then we close all open environments

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5

\newsavebox\Authorbox
\sbox\Authorbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5in, height=0.5in]{Agri1.jpg}}
% now place the picture
\rput[lb](0.5,2.1){\usebox\Authorbox}

% create a savebx for the biography. The width has been adjusted so
% that the right margin matches with that of the book blurb
\newsavebox\Biobox
\sbox\Biobox{\begin{minipage}{3.6in}
\textcolor{white}{%
    \large{%
AB  \LaTeX{}. Contact him
by at bla@bla.com
  }
 }

\end{minipage}}
% and put it where it belongs
\rput[tl](1.9,2.9){\usebox\Biobox}

\rput(5.0,-1.2){
\colorbox{white}{\EANisbn[SC1]}}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the document with `xelatex` ...

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Herbert for your nice answer. It works like a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you also help me to put an image as wallpaper? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by wallpaper? An image over the complete textwidht, height or paper?

Comment: Please have a look on page 17 Fig 7 in this [link](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/robbers/robbers.pdf). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That is only a `\rput` command as already explained in the document.